# withLatestFrom for hot observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

`a$.pipe(withLatestFrom(b$))` emits value only if `b$` is cold observable (or Behavior/ReplaySubject).
But what if both `a$` and `b$` are hot observables ?
I this case resulting observable will never emit

I think the solution would be to do

```
b2$ = b$.pipe(publishReplay(1))
b2$.connect()
```

and then

```
a$.pipe(withLatestFrom(b2$))
```

but it doesn't look right to me. What would be proper solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`a$.pipe(withLatestFrom(b$))` will emit when `b$` emits first and `a$` emits second.

If you want the resulting observable to emit as soon as `a$` emits while `b$` hasn't emitted yet you can use `startWith` to add an initial value to `b$`.

```ts
a$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(b$.pipe(startWith(null)))
)
```

Comment: Consider the case when 
`const bSubj = new Subject();bSubj.next('value');const b$ = bSubj.asObservable()`
in this case `a$.pipe(withLatestFrom(b$))` will never emit

Comment: @dps if `b$` doesn't emit anything then `a$.pipe(withLatestFrom(b$))` won't emit anything - yes. What's your point?